# Meaning of シャキン or シャッキン used to support someone

Tags: manga, onomatopoeia, sports

In a manga, before the start of a boxing match, one of the boxers looks at his friends in the audience and says:

> シャキ〜ン

Then they reply more or less in the same way:

> しゃっきい〜ん

What is the meaning of this expression? Is it an onomatopoeic word used to support someone? Since the match has a special prize of one million yen for the winner, could it be 謝金? [Here you can see the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MljF.jpg) where it is taken from. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can hear a lot of シャキーン sounds in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBwwOCeL1OI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an onomatopoeia originally mimics the sound some metallic material makes when it swiftly extends, like the way the joint makes when a folding knife springs out. But it is also used to express (comically) that someone feels at 100% condition or full of spirit.

It's often uttered with striking certain poses. See [here](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3).

[image]

Comment: So it is similar to "頑張れ!"?

Comment: @Marco Mmm... it's usually what they say by themselves rather than others say to them. In your situation, supporters seem just echoing the word, but I don't know much about the plot.

Answer (score 2):

「シャキ～ン」 is an onomatopoeia expressing one's feeling when bracing oneself up just before or at the start of an important event.  Round 1 is just starting here so, that is how he feels.

「しゃっきい〜ん」 said by that girl would be a pun-like joke.  「借金{しゃっきん}」 means "debt(s)".

I do not see how 「謝金{しゃきん}」 ("renumeration") would be uttered here.  It is a much bigger (and less often used) word than 「借金」.

Comment: I haven't read this manga, but I doubt an elementary school girl would be making a pun on 借金...

Comment: 「借金」って本当ですか？　この登場人物が借金持ちという設定は見つけられませんでしたが、仮に借金持ちだとしても、この無垢な顔の子供が相手の「シャキーン」に対して「お前の場合はシャキーンやなくて借金やろー」とツッコミを入れている可能性は限りなく低いと思いますが。